# Release Variables through REST API - Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio, rest, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to pass variable values to the REST endpoint for Release Management in VSTS? E.g. Calling `PUT https://tfs.vsrm.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/{project}/_apis/release/releases/30?api-version=3.0-preview.4` with the request of:

```
{
  "id": 30,
  "name": "Release-3",
  "variables": {
    "VariableName": {
      "value": "testing123"
    }
  }
}
```

I somehow managed to get it to work if I call `POST https://k2tfs.vsrm.visualstudio.com/density/_apis/release/releases/?api-version=3.0-preview.4` then take that response and use it in the request above. Is this the only way?

Comment: Can you post back your complete answer for others to use? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t the way to change variable value when create a new release.

Regarding your way, it modifies the created release variable value, the changed value can be used when deploy the release.

Another way is that, you can create a draft release,

Post:

```
https://[account].vsrm.visualstudio.com/[project]/_apis/release/releases/?api-version=3.0-preview.4
```

application/json:

```
{
  "definitionId": [release definition id],
  "isDraft":true
}
```

then update variables’ value (as you said)

after that, you can start the release by [Modifying the status of a release](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#modify-the-status-of-a-release) (active)

```
{
    "status": "Active"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you can define VSTS Release variables to be "Settable at release time". Then passing variable values at the time of creating a release is possible in VSTS REST API. You can do same when you try to Create a release in VSTS WEB UI as well. for more information refer [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283685/vsts-rest-api-create-release/51925393#51925393).