# VSTS Rest API - Create Release

Tags: azure-devops, release

I'd like to start a release leveraging the VSTS Rest API defined here:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#create-a-release

but I need to set some of the variable values when I create the release. 
Looking at the ReleaseMetadata (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/contracts#ReleaseStartMetadata) I see there is a properties collection.  Is this where I'd set the variable values?  Is there any special naming convention I need to use in the property name to translate it the variable name? (like ##VSTS:[])??

Comment: Hi cdarrigo, any update on this issue? Did my reply helped or gave a right direction. It's not able to set variable values when you created a release for now.

Answer (score 8):

Now you can define VSTS Release variables to be "Settable at release time" as shown below.
[image]

Then you can use below json syntax in [VSTS REST API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1) request body to pass the variable values to set at the time of creating the release.

```
"variables": {
    "Variable1Name": {
      "value": "Variable1Value"
    },
    "Variable2Name": {
      "value": "Variable2Value"
    }
  }
```

[image]

For more information refer the [post here](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2018/08/setting-vsts-release-variable-values-at.html).

Comment: For anyone searching for this now, this works and should be the accepted answer. Patrick's answer was correct at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for now it's **not able to set variable values** when you created a release. This is unlike Build definition for VSTS, variables are allowed to change their values at queue time.

There has been a related uservoice, you could vote for it:

> **Change release variables' value when deploy a release**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/16616269-change-release-variables-value-when-deploy-a-rele

As a workaround,  you could create a draft release, then update variables’ value ,after that, you can start the release by [Modifying the status of a release](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#modify-the-status-of-a-release) (active)

```
{
    "status": "Active"
}
```

More detail info please take a look this similar question: [Release Variables through REST API - Visual Studio Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677286/release-variables-through-rest-api-visual-studio-team-services)