# How to GET variables used in a specific BUILD in Azure Devops / TFS via api

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, psobject

From within both Build & Release pipelines in Azure Devops, I'm triggering other pipelines via api.

I am trying to get my release pipeline to harvest custom variables that were discovered / used during the associated build.

I'm able to get a list of builds via get api, and i'm able to spawn other builds and pass parameters to them.

While I can spawn a release via api, I have been unsuccessful in passing parameters... or harvesting parameters on-demand at the time of Create Release.

I have reviewed Microsoft's documentation and successfully queued Builds via api with custom parameters and created releases without custom parameters.

```
[String]$buildID = "$env:BUILD_BUILDID"
[String]$project = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"
[String]$projecturi = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI"
[String]$alias = "drop"

$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }
$url= $projecturi + $project + "/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0-preview"

$JSON = @"
{
  "definitionId": 9,
  "description": "Testing API Release",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "$alias",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "$buildID",
        "name": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "isDraft": false,
  "reason": "none",
  "manualEnvironments": null
}
"@

Write-Host $url
$responseRelease = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -headers $headers -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $JSON

Write-Host $responseRelease
```

The results of the current code creates a release, but don't pass custom variables (or harvest custom variables from a completed build). I would rather pass or harvest them than recalculate them.

Comment: I'm hoping that there's a way to read-in variables from a build... because I'm assuming that I'm still unable to pass variables into a release based on this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283685/vsts-rest-api-create-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First as you have mentioned in the comment, it's not able to directly change variables when deploy a release. As a user voice on Road map:

> **Change release variables' value when deploy a release**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365596/change-release-variables-value-when-deploy-a-relea.html.

According to your description, seems you want to access the Build variables from Release definition. This is also not a build-in feature at present.

As a workaround, try to use this 3rd-party Azure DevOps extension [Variable Tools for Azure DevOps Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.variablehydration).

In the "build pipeline" you can create a JSON file using "save variables". This file needs to **be published as artifact** or with existing artifact.

In the "release pipeline" you can restore the variables using "load variables" from the JSON file.

Another way is storing the variable’s value in [Variable Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) and link the variable group into your release definition.

During release, you can get variable groups firstly, and filter the variable under the variable `group-$(Build.BuildId)`.